# How to get Facebook inline video sharing to work

Tags: facebook, share, jwplayer

I have a video site with re-written url's of embedded youtube videos. I want to share a playable video in jwplayer on Facebook. I found this snippet for jwplayer to help, but doesn't seem to help.

http://www.longtailvideo.com/sites/default/files/facebookfeednew.png

```
<meta property="og:description" content="Big Buck Bunny is a short animated film by the Blender Institute. It is made using free and open source software."/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://content.bitsontherun.com/thumbs/nPripu9l-320.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Big Buck Bunny"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Big Buck Bunny Trailer"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="movie"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/"/>
<meta property="og:video" content="https://content.bitsontherun.com/players/nPripu9l-8toGQxMR.swf" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="270" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="480" />
```

specially no video.flv path,demo like: ![enter image description here][1]

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/addons/sharing-plugin/14048/facebook-video-sharing
I am no expert with this stuff. Please Help.